# Cambiar color de letras en php y html dependiento del resultado de una condicional

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server

¡Hola! Hace años no desarrollo paginas web, y decidi volver a hacerlo con html y php. Hago una consulta de una vista a una base de datos y dependiendo del resultado busco que cambie de color el texto.
este es mi codigo para hacer la consulta

```
$stmt = $conn->query($query2);
$registros = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Y el siguiente es mi codigo con el que muestro la consulta

```
  <?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :  ?>
 <tr>
   <th scope="row">  <?php if( $fila->AV_GREEN!="0"){
       echo "Campos llenos";
     }else {
             echo "Campos vacios";
     } ?></th>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

En el resultado de if necesito que sea de color rojo si el campo es diferente a cero. Pero no logro encontrar como hacerlo. el resultado que me arroja es de una serie de numeros.
[image: Resultado hasta ahora]

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que usar CSS (`color:red`), y se puede hacer de muchas maneras, aquí un par:

#### Usando Style

```
<?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :  ?>
 <tr>
   <?php 
     if( $fila->AV_GREEN!="0"){
       echo '<th scope="row" style="color:red">'; 
       echo "Campos llenos";
     }else {
       echo '<th scope="row">';   
       echo "Campos vacios";
     } 
     echo '</th>';
   ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

#### Usando clases

Primero creas un CSS

```
.llenos{
  color:red;
}
```

```
<?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :  ?>
 <tr>
  <?php 
   $clase="";
   $texto="Campos vacios";
   if( $fila->AV_GREEN!="0"){
     $clase="llenos";
     $texto="Campos llenos";
   }?>
   <th scope="row" class="<?php echo clase; ?>">
      <?php echo texto; ?>
   </th>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

#### El texto con CSS

Incluso puedes poner el texto con css

```
.campos:after{
  content: 'Campos vacios';
}
.llenos:after{
  content: 'Campos llenos';
  color:red;
}
```

```
<?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :  ?>
 <tr>
   <th scope="row" class="campos <?php echo $fila->AV_GREEN!="0"?"llenos":""; ?>"></th>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```